# Is there a way to position md-tooltip relative to mouse cursor?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I want to position a `md-tooltip` element relative to where the mouse cursor is, similar to when you hover the progress bar in a YouTube video. I have the following simplified structure:

```
<div id="timerBar">
    <div id="progressBar"></div>
    <div id="bufferBar"></div>
    <div id="remainingBar"></div>
    <md-tooltip></md-tooltip>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently yes there is:

```
<div id="timerBar" ng-mouseenter="setTooltip($event)" ng-mousemove="setTooltip($event)">
    <div id="progressBar"></div>
    <div id="bufferBar"></div>
    <div id="remainingBar"></div>
    <md-tooltip id="slider-tooltip" style="-ms-transition: none; -o-transition: none; -webkit-transition: none; transition: none;"></md-tooltip>
</div>
```

And the AngularJS/jQuery function:

```
$scope.setTooltip = function (e) {
    $("#slider-tooltip").css("left", e.clientX - $("#slider-tooltip").width()/2);
}
```